# ¿como saco el valor de varios checkbox para guardarlo en una variable expresado en una función?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, input, checkbox

estoy estudiando actualmente soy muy noob, y estoy estancado. Tengo varios checkbox que tienen un valor asociado, y quiero que al clickar esos valores se sumen y se guarden en una variable que luego sumare a otras variables para pintarlas en un input que se actualiza de forma automática (es como un campo de presupuesto). De hecho el alert que tengo puesto ni llega a saltar. No se muy bien como expresarlo en la función, he probado varias cosas pero no consigo meter los valores en la variable, estoy un poco perdido a ver si me podéis ayudar.

El js:

```
    var valorExtras = '';
    
    $(extras).on('change', sumarExtras);
    
    function sumarExtras() {
    
        valorExtras = '';
    
        $('input.checkbox_check:checked').each(function() {
            valorExtras += parseInt($(this).val());
            alert(valorExtras);
        });
    
        document.getElementById('presup').value = parseInt(valorExtras) + parseInt(total) + parseInt(precioProducto) + ' €';
    }
```

y la parte del HTML de esto:

```
<div id="extras">
                    <div id="extrasPubli">
                        <p> Extras para el producto: </p> <br><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="publi" value="100"> Publicidad en redes 
                        <input type="checkbox" id="reel" value="75"> Reel promocional 
                        <input type="checkbox" id="distri" value="50"> Distribución digital <br><br>
                    </div>
                    <div id="extrasHoras">
                        <p> Extras para el producto: </p> <br><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="24h" value="150"> 24h 
                        <input type="checkbox" id="48h" value="300"> 48h 
                        <input type="checkbox" id="72h" value="500"> 72h <br> <br>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p>Presupuesto estimado: </p><input type="text" id="presup" value="" readonly> <br><br>
```

Un saludo!!

Comment: Necesitas que se sumen los values de los inputs dependiendo de si esten "checked" o no?

Comment: Si están checked, que el valor asociado a cada uno se guarde en una variable para después sumarlas con las demás. Ya lo solucioné, gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo el ejemplo funcionando.

El problema es que estas seleccionando mal los inputs,

tenias `$('input.checkbox_check:checked')` pero debes poner es `input[type=checkbox]:checked`.

El alert lo debes sacar del `each` (Yo lo cambié por un console.log para no interrumpir la ejecucion)

```js
$(extras).on('change', sumarExtras);
var total = 20; //Les pongo un valor fijo para que el ejemplo no saque error
var precioProducto = 30; //Les pongo un valor fijo para que el ejemplo no saque error

function sumarExtras() {

  valorExtras = 0;

  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    valorExtras += parseInt($(this).val());
  });

  console.log("Total Valor Extras", valorExtras);
  document.getElementById('presup').value = parseInt(valorExtras) + parseInt(total) + parseInt(precioProducto) + ' €';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="extras">
  <div id="extrasPubli">
    <p> Extras para el producto: </p> <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="publi" value="100"> Publicidad en redes
    <input type="checkbox" id="reel" value="75"> Reel promocional
    <input type="checkbox" id="distri" value="50"> Distribución digital <br><br>
  </div>
  <div id="extrasHoras">
    <p> Extras para el producto: </p> <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="24h" value="150"> 24h
    <input type="checkbox" id="48h" value="300"> 48h
    <input type="checkbox" id="72h" value="500"> 72h <br> <br>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Presupuesto estimado: </p><input type="text" id="presup" value="" readonly> <br><br>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! me has ayudado mazo llevaba unos días ya mareado con el tema, un saludo!